# Battlecode 2015 ant run causes nullPointerException in Win32ShellFolder2 class

Tags: java, ant, nullpointerexception

I want to participate in this year's [battlecode 2015](https://www.battlecode.org/).
I've downloaded the project and ran the ant (build.xml) file in eclipse.
Here's the file: http://pastebin.com/M5YcJTdz

Here's the part that causes the exception:

```
  <target name="run" depends="build">
    <java 
     classpathref="classpath.run"
     fork="yes"
     classname="battlecode.client.Main">
      <jvmarg value="-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true"/>
      <jvmarg value="-Dbc.server.map-path=${path.maps}"/>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256m"/> 
      <jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=${path.lib}" />
      <arg line="-c bc.conf"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

And here's the exception:

```
Buildfile: C:\Robot\Robot\Battlecode\build.xml
-init:
build-scala:
build:
run:
     [java] x86
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]     at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Win32ShellFolder2.java:72)
     [java]     at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:242)
     [java]     at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:237)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     [java]     at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:511)
     [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     [java] Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Using Windows 8, latest eclipse, Java SDK 7 and 8. Tried both 64 and 32 bit architecture.

It looks like other users don't have such problem.

Source code for the client:
https://github.com/battlecode/battlecode-client/blob/master/src/main/battlecode/client/Main.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an access failure to one of the special Windows shell folders. Try running the Ant/Java process as Administrator, or from another user account, in case your current user account is hosed somehow.

Or you could try tracing the code in some manner (I'm hand-waving here, assuming you don't want to do this...) to find out what system or user folder it is barfing on, and going from there.

Comment: Any idea how to run ant in eclipse as administrator ?
Creating a new windows 8 user might fix it. I'll try that.

Comment: Creating a new windows 8 user did it... arrghh Java! Another 3 hours wasted.